# Reporting fall semester grades

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

A couple of graduate schools I have applied to have a section for reporting the Fall semester grades (the application deadlines were before the end of the Fall semester). My GPA has decreased by 0.1 and my previously-outstanding GPA is not outstanding anymore, and even though I haven't received any terrible grades (my grades were A, A-, and B+), I don't have a straight-A transcript any more. That being said, I have two more graduate-level courses in related topics with decent grades. Now I am wondering whether in this situation I should report the new grades or I shouldn't, given that it is an optional section of the application to be completed after submission.

I appreciate your comments on that.

Comment: perhaps not the best dupe but it would surprise me to discover this is the first time this has been asked.

Comment: @virmaior It is not a duplicate of that question because I am asking whether it is better to report or not, not if I can report or not. There is a designated section on the application portal for reporting the Fall semester grades.

Comment: If they ask you to report it, do. If they don't, you don't need to... Basically no one in your department should care about that. Maybe the graduate school itself does but if it's not required, skip it?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, honestly, congrats on the excellent transcript. Not many people can say they have a straight A- transcript. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Were those "bad" grades in important classes? How challenging were they?
Don't want to beat a dead horse but I think professors would understand if you got a B+ in some engineering calculus class but would raise questions if the B+ was in a freshman GE class.

Again, congrats, and as long as your GPA is above the 3.0 minimum, (which it sounds like it isn't) I wouldn't stress too much